# Conversion from byte[] to hexadecimal in order to perform sql query

Tags: c#, mysql, sql-server, hash, type-conversion

so in my database I have a computed column that contains an MD5 hash id. On sql server it looks like this:

```
0x9D5C3DFE63EA502A31FB18D8A55E88C3
```

Now, I query the database in my code and transform the hash id into a string by doing:

```
BitConverter.ToString(row.Field<Byte[]>(HashId)).Replace("-", "");
```

And the result is:

```
9D5C3DFE63EA502A31FB18D8A55E88C3
```

What I do need now, by having this string, is to query again the database and, through a WHERE condition, retrieve the records in the table whose hashId match the string. So, first of all I convert back the string into Byte[] (otherwise there is a mismatch of types) in order to use it in my sql query. I do this by using a method I found here on stackoverflow:

```
public static byte[] ToByte(this string str)
    {
        byte[] bytes = new byte[str.Length * sizeof(char)];
        System.Buffer.BlockCopy(str.ToCharArray(), 0, bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
    }
```

but this is not enough unfortunately. Because the problem it seems to be the missing **0x** at the beginning.. which I cannot easily append back to the array of bytes. How can I solve this problem? thanks in advance

Comment: What is the data type of the column in the table?

Comment: computed type, it's indeed byte[] because of the result of the MD5 computation

Comment: Did you try to prepend string with `0x` and then convert string to byte array?